# Any way to make Rust understand an `fn(T) -> impl Future` always returns the same type?

Tags: generics, rust, future

I've a function which takes a generic parameter, gets what it needs out of that, then returns a future. The future does not actually store the generic data, it is completely monomorphic.

For convenience I wanted to use an `async fn` to create the future, which I understand requires returning an `impl Future` as `async fn` return opaque types: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c3b061d12a126dc30099ac3bd018c273

```rust
use std::io::{Read, stdin};
use std::fs::File;
use std::future::Future;
use std::path::Path;

fn caller(p: Option<&Path>) -> impl Future<Output=()> {
    if let Some(p) = p {
        f(File::open(p).unwrap())
    } else {
        f(stdin())
    }
}

fn f<R: Read>(_: R) -> impl Future<Output=()> {
    fut()
}

async fn fut() {}
```

However rustc freaks out in the conditional as the caller side is absolutely convinced the future must somehow be different between the two branches:

```
error[E0308]: `if` and `else` have incompatible types
  --> src/lib.rs:10:9
   |
7  | /     if let Some(p) = p {
8  | |         f(File::open(p).unwrap())
   | |         ------------------------- expected because of this
9  | |     } else {
10 | |         f(stdin())
   | |         ^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `File`, found struct `Stdin`
11 | |     }
   | |_____- `if` and `else` have incompatible types
...
14 |   fn f<R: Read>(_: R) -> impl Future<Output=()> {
   |                          ---------------------- the found opaque type
   |
   = note:     expected type `impl Future<Output = ()>` (struct `File`)
           found opaque type `impl Future<Output = ()>` (struct `Stdin`)
```

Is there a way to fix this aside from boxing the future or hand-rolling `fut` in order to end up with a single concrete type?

Comment: If you make `caller` an `async fn` then it can just `.await` the futures within each branch, resulting in a new future of a single opaque type.  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=98c74f19f55b195dc2363023218a0b47

Comment: Alternatively, you could return an [`Either`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/enum.Either.html).

Comment: @eggyal sadly in the real codebase `caller` is the `main` function, is in the process of setting up the event loop, and `fut` is an infinite message-processing loop.

Comment: Then use `Either`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid boxing, but at least you can avoid boxing the future itself:

```rust
use std::io::{Read, stdin};
use std::fs::File;
use std::future::Future;
use std::path::Path;

fn caller(p: Option<&Path>) -> impl Future<Output=()> {
    let read = if let Some(p) = p {
        Box::new(File::open(p).unwrap()) as Box<dyn Read>
    } else {
        Box::new(stdin())
    };
    f(read)
}

fn f<R: Read>(_: R) -> impl Future<Output=()> {
    fut()
}

async fn fut() {}
```

As my understanding, the problem is not the future, but that is actually building different types for the parameters, and somehow floods into the return type. It would makes sense it wouldn't though.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=473f0477adaeff4f4d222712bb834144)

Comment: From this I guess passing in an `&mut dyn Read` should also work fine, it avoids the boxing, though like your suggestion it switches over to dynamically dispatching the `Read`.

Comment: @Masklinn, yes, you could use a `&mut Read`, but somehow you need to fit the types into a single strict one for the compiler to understand it. Maybe is something worth to ask for a fix? Not sure if it is even possible.

Comment: Welp the `&dyn Read` version doesn't work either because now rustc considers the future to require the borrow, same as the bound. So box it is (and a search through the rustc tracker).

Comment: welp [issue 42940](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42940) popped up immediately when I looked it up on github, though it was nowhere I could see in the google results. Apparently [impl trait alias](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42940#issuecomment-530542159) should eventually provide an efficient workaround, in the meantime I guess boxing it is. Thanks for your help.

Comment: [TAIT can do it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d20459dd81cad803113eece82508d37c) but is limited because of unification.